# Netbeans missing code hints for PHP

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, netbeans

I'm having a problem with Netbeans 8.1 working on Symfony2 project - I don't have any code hints and autocomplete suggestions. It applies to both userland code written by me and autoloaded from vendors.

For example when I want to implement an interface, there's no hint for missing methods. I don't even get autocomplete for `$this`.

I already tried to clear cache directory with no success.

My Netbeans info:

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 20151231-debian-8.1)
>
> Java: 1.8.0_111; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.111-b14
>
> Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14
>
> Running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Perhaps someone had that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I excluded vendors directory in Netbeans project properties. I did it when I wanted Netbeans to use code sniffer.
Maybe you'll find it helpful information.

Comment: I didn't exclude any directories in my Netbeans project properties. Unfortunately I can't make it work, I have Symfony2 and Doctrine2 support enabled and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Netbeans 8.2 solved the issue (I'm not sure if it would not work with reinstallation of Netbeans 8.1).

I had to download new version from https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html because it was not available through apt.